# How do I run Firefox nightly on 10.10?

Tags: 10.10, firefox, software-sources

How does one install firefox nightly on ubuntu maveric (10.10) ?

This is what I have done so far

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox-trunk
```

I get the following error : `Unable to locate package firefox-trunk`

[Here](http://pastebin.com/8ZuPDM9B) is a log of the update command, in which it has s surprising IGN next to mozilla daily ppa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the contents of the PPA itself:

- https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-mozilla-daily/+archive/ppa/+packages

You'll see that there are no packages currently being built for 10.10 in that PPA.

Comment: oh. yeah. My bad.